# A verb for 'gentle slow-motion wriggling'

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I look for a verb that conveys **gentle slow-motion wriggling**.

For example, the octopus tentacle ... further into the sand.

According to the classical dictionaries OEL, OALD, CALD, etc. wriggling conveys
with *short writhing motions* like a worm. I'm looking for a word that does not insinuate *writhing*.

**NOTE**
Words like *to drill, to bore, etc.* do not fit here, because of the context of the sentence. My real sentence is different but the octopus tentacle conveys the idea of the movement.

My sentence is about a tangible sensation that permeates the body slowly over time, and that sensation has a clear physicalness, it's not an imagination. However, it can't be measured although the effect of it worming through the body should be measurable. (Somewhat similar to measuring the Higgs boson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try *slithering* or *worming*

Comment: I don't think you can worm or slither a tentacle.

Comment: Why not? "The octopus tentacle slithered further into the sand." But,  "The octopus tentacle wormed *its way* further into the sand."

Comment: Slither also insinuates 'quick and easy', at least according to my dictionaries. Hence, not possible. ...'to worm' ... is not too bad.

Comment: @LorelC. Sorry, but only an animal (or insect) or person can slither or worm their way into  something. An animal or human appendage cannot do so. Basic usage. We  would not say: I slithered my arm into the hole. But we would say: I slithered into the hole.

Comment: @Lambie "_Slowly, gently, the door to the closet swung open and a green-and-yellow-splotched tentacle slithered out and across the floor._" --[Dreamland](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z_1WAAAAYAAJ&q=%22tentacle+slithered%22&dq=%22tentacle+slithered%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBipWm4tXiAhULh-AKHclmAY8Q6AEITzAG), from the author of Star Trek

Comment: @EddieKai That means the tentacle is separated from whatever it had been attached to and has become "an animal of some kind" in its own right.

Comment: @LorelC. That's the way I meant my answer. In my understanding a snake, worm or tentacle (attached or otherwise) could slither or worm itself. Worming especially suggests burrowing, which could be a third option.

Comment: I am going with 'to worm'. That should work. Great input, all! Thank you!